# How can I make Excel visually update cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I am using Excel 2016. I have a small spreadsheet that is exhibiting some unusual display problems.

When I recalculate a range, which includes all cells on the sheet with content or formulas, two columns which call UDFs do not visually update the calling cells after the calculation completes.

The UDF code executes, but the function return values (one is Text, one is Variant) are not displayed -- the previous value remain displayed in the cell. If I go to either of these columns and "re-enter" the calculation in a cell by pressing ENTER, both columns visually update to the expected values.

Other columns with UDF calls do not exhibit this problem.

Comment: help us to help you; **post your current code.**

Comment: Could you provide your problem sample?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, posting the exact code is not possible. I can however describe the two UDFs. The first takes input from the sheet and potentially creates some textual output into a file. The function returns info about the operation. The second UDF returns the last modification date of the file that was created (or created previously).

Comment: UDFs shouldn't take input from a sheet. UDFs take input as parameters to the UDF and will change only the value in the cell (or the routine) where they are called from. It sounds like you should use a SUB instead.